# ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment-mount-provider

Tags: java, eclipse, jboss7.x

I can run my Jboss server without problems from the command line but via  eclipse i get the following error. In the server Details i can see the server is "Not connected" and after the timeout is expired (450 sec) stops trying to be connected.

I need to be able to start the jboss via eclise so as to facilitate the deploy process and be able to debug the code.

This is the error log...

```
12:26:21,740 INFO  [org.jboss.modules] JBoss Modules version 1.1.1.GA
12:26:21,942 INFO  [org.jboss.msc] JBoss MSC version 1.0.2.GA
12:26:22,002 INFO  [org.jboss.as] JBAS015899: JBoss AS 7.1.1.Final "Brontes" starting
12:26:22,116 ERROR [org.jboss.msc.service.fail] MSC00001: Failed to start service jboss.deployment-mount-provider: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment-mount-provider: JBAS015843: Failed to create temp file provider
    at org.jboss.as.server.deployment.DeploymentMountProvider$Factory$ServerDeploymentRepositoryImpl.start(DeploymentMountProvider.java:111) [jboss-as-server-7.1.1.Final.jar:7.1.1.Final]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.startService(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1811) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at org.jboss.msc.service.ServiceControllerImpl$StartTask.run(ServiceControllerImpl.java:1746) [jboss-msc-1.0.2.GA.jar:1.0.2.GA]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1110) [rt.jar:1.6.0_23]
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:603) [rt.jar:1.6.0_23]
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:679) [rt.jar:1.6.0_23]
```

Could someone please help with this problem.

Comment: have you looked at this thread https://community.jboss.org/message/739455?_sscc=t ?

Answer (score 1):

This error is getting displayed, because maybe you do not have appropriate permissions for that folder. Switch user to root user and try to run the 'standalone.sh' command. I guess that will solve you problem. Else change permissions in your user.

Answer (score 0):

The error is due to the unavailability of enough memory space.
Please check the tmp folder under standalone folder of your Jboss.
Clear its contents using

```
rm -rfv tmp/*
```

Then restart your Jboss server.